# /Applications/ArangoDB3-CLI.app/Contents/MacOS//var/log/arangodb3/arangod.log: No such file or directory

Tags: arangodb

I installed the .dmg file of ArangoDB and I am not able to start the server as the following error is displayed in the CLI of ArrangoDB

```
ArangoDB server has been started

The database directory is located at
   '/Applications/ArangoDB3-CLI.app/Contents/MacOS//var/lib/arangodb3'

The log file is located at
   '/Applications/ArangoDB3-CLI.app/Contents/MacOS//var/log/arangodb3/arangod.log'

You can access the server using a browser at 'http://127.0.0.1:8529/'
or start the ArangoDB shell
   '/Applications/ArangoDB3-CLI.app/Contents/MacOS/arangosh'

Switching to log-file now, killing this windows will NOT stop the server.


tail: /Applications/ArangoDB3-CLI.app/Contents/MacOS//var/log/arangodb3/arangod.log: No such file or directory

[Process completed]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: 3.1.1 released. Please download the new bugfix release. The issue should be gone then.  [Download 3.1.1 MacOS](https://www.arangodb.com/download/macosx/). If you still get the same error, install openssl using the following command

```
brew install openssl
```

(Note: if you're using Sierra, update Xcode to 8.1)

Please put ArangoDB3-CLI into applications folder:

> /Applications

Then the database will startup properly. 
This was just a temporary workaround. All upcoming versions of ArangoDB (3.1.1+) will work in any directory.

Comment: Still the same error though I have added the ArangoDB3-CLI.app file in the above mentioned path